# angular.js: $sanitize fails on $injector:modulerr using exact code example from angular site

Tags: javascript, angularjs

UPDATE:

steps to reproduce:

1. visit this link :http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize
2. click on 'EDIT' button top right of code sample.
3. select jsfiddle or plnkr

expected result: will see the html output under the 'rendered' heading

I  am trying to implement html binding.
Curiously, I can't get a working example using the exact code from this example:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize

It works on angular site, but not elsewhere.

I have tried using the edit link to plunk and jsfiddle, with no results.
Running locally I get this error in console:

here is what I get in console:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ngSanitize">
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        Snippet: <textarea ng-model="snippet" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Directive</td>
          <td>How</td>
          <td>Source</td>
          <td>Rendered</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="bind-html-with-sanitize">
          <td>ng-bind-html</td>
          <td>Automatically uses $sanitize</td>
          <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>
          <td><div ng-bind-html="snippet"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="bind-html-with-trust">
          <td>ng-bind-html</td>
          <td>Bypass $sanitize by explicitly trusting the dangerous value</td>
          <td>
          <pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"&gt;
        t;/div&gt;</pre>
          </td>
          <td><div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-default">
          <td>ng-bind</td>
          <td>Automatically escapes</td>
          <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>
          <td><div ng-bind="snippet"></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.snippet =
    '<p style="color:blue">an html\n' +
    '<em onmouseover="this.textContent=\'PWN3D!\'">click here</em>\n' +
    'snippet</p>';
  $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
  };
}
```

Comment: Do you have both the angular.sanitize script in the header and did you inject it into the your app?

Comment: I did not touch the code. I used working code example from angular site, and it does not work outside of the site. I am updating the answer wit the code.

Comment: Can we see what you have exactly or provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @dcodesmith: what I have is exactly the code on the link provided: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize. Its a challenge to get whole code into the question using insert code function. the formatting goes haywire.

Comment: do you have `<script src="angular-sanitize.js">` somewhere on the your page?

Comment: please see steps to reproduce. I wrote zero code. I am using edit feature on agular site to view their code in js fiddle or plnkr

Comment: I added the script tag (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-sanitize.js) to angular's code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9YigAvkxa984AMeZZied?p=preview. does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There error was self explanatory, you didn't include the angualar.sanitize.js script in the fiddle or plunkr.

I added the below script tag below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/reLSF/)**